# Why does comments_open() return false when publishing a scheduled post?

Tags: plugin-development

My plugin does stuff whenever a post is published and comments are enabled for that post. It works fine when publishing a post as normal, but if a scheduled post is published, it doesn't.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
function do_stuff( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    global $post;

    if ( !comments_open( $post->ID ) ) {
        return;
    }

    /* do stuff */
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'do_stuff', 10, 3 );
```

After some debugging, I was surprised to find the problem was `comments_open()` returning `FALSE`, every single time a scheduled post was published, regardless of the "Allow Comments" setting.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you check what `$post->comment_status` returns in these cases?

Comment: No, `$post->comment_status` is empty when a scheduled post is published. I'm guessing this is why `comments_open()` doesn't work, because the `$post` object hasn't been fully initialized yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by referencing the `global $post` object. The `global $post` has not yet been initialized with the new post's details, so checking to see whether or not its comments are open will always return false at the `transition_post_status` hook.

The `$post` variable passed to my `do_stuff()` function *does* contain all the correct information about my new post, so I work with it instead. I eventually ended up with something like the following, which functions correctly with both regular and scheduled posts:

```
function do_stuff( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
   if ( $post->comment_status == 'closed' ) {
     return;
   }

   /* do stuff */
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'do_stuff', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Ah, good catch, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: Thank you...your post helped me with a different but similar situation.  Comments were disabled...because a shortcode in the page didn't reset the global post.  I added wp_reset_postdata(); to the end of the shortcode function and that did the trick.  Hope this helps others.